# PlacePicker.IntentBuilder closes immediately after opening

Tags: android, user-interface, android-intent

I implemented the PlacePicker.IntentBuilder UI into my application.  For the longest it worked with no problem but now as soon as the UI appears, it closes and im not sure why. The crazy thing is looking at the logcat it doesn't crash or cause any exceptions so I don't know what the issue is. This is the class that creates and calls it.

```
    package com.example.apthagreat.faf;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;


    public class DetermineSearchCoordinatesScreen extends ActionBarActivity
    {
        //Instance Variables
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    int SELECTED_PLACE_REQUEST = 2;
    LatLng southWestBounds;
    LatLng northEastBounds;
    String zipCodeString;
    String zipCodeURL;
    String user;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_determine_search_coordinates_screen);
        final EditText zipCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterZip);
        final Button findZip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findZipButton);
        user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        //Find button is used when user enters a zip code and not the device's GPS
        findZip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (findZip.getText().equals("FIND!"))
                {
                    //build the URL to be passed to determine coordinates for given zip code
                    zipCodeURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
                    zipCodeString = zipCode.getText().toString();
                    if (zipCodeString.length() == 5)
                    {
                        //Fetch to go get GPS coordinates for zip code
                        zipCodeURL += zipCodeString;
                        GetZipCoordinates task = new GetZipCoordinates(southWestBounds, northEastBounds);
                        task.execute(zipCodeURL);
                        findZip.setText("PUSH TO SEE PLACES");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Must enter a valid 5 digit zip code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                else if (findZip.getText().equals("PUSH TO SEE PLACES"))
                {
                    //AsyncTask was successful in finding coordinates and now we can pass the coordinates in and display places to user
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    LatLngBounds llb = new LatLngBounds(southWestBounds, northEastBounds);
                    builder.setLatLngBounds(llb);
                    findZip.setText("FIND!");
                    try
                    {
                        startActivityForResult(builder.build(DetermineSearchCoordinatesScreen.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                    }
                    catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException npe)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Retrieval of coordinates is not yet complete! Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        //Here we will use the device's GPS coordinates and display nearby places
        Button currentSpot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentLocationButton);
        currentSpot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(DetermineSearchCoordinatesScreen.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                }
                catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search_category_location_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setNorthEastBounds(LatLng northEastBounds)
    {
        this.northEastBounds = northEastBounds;
    }

    public void setSouthWestBounds(LatLng southWestBounds)
    {
        this.southWestBounds = southWestBounds;
    }

    /*
        Once the user selects a place, a dialog will appear prompting the user if they would like
        to create an activity at this place
     */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                //The place the user selected
                final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                //The dialog that will prompt the user to create an activity when a place is selected
                AlertDialog.Builder createActivity = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                createActivity.setMessage("Would you like to create an activity at this location?");
                createActivity.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        //Here the user will be directed to the create activity screen and the name and address of selected place will be passed along with it
                        Intent create = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateActivityScreen.class);
                        create.putExtra("username", user);
                        create.putExtra("placeName", place.getName());
                        create.putExtra("placeAddress", place.getAddress());
                        startActivityForResult(create, SELECTED_PLACE_REQUEST);

                        finish();
                    }
                });
                createActivity.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        //If the user doesn't want to create an activity nothing will happen
                    }
                });
                createActivity.show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
        The class that is taking the URL and fetching to the internet to find
        the GPS coordinates for the user given zip code.
        Parses the data into a JSON object and converts it into Latitude and Longitude
        coordinates.
        The coordinates are given in the form of the Southwest bound coordinates and
        Northeast bound coordinates around the zip code.
     */
    private class GetZipCoordinates extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        LatLng sw;
        LatLng ne;

        public GetZipCoordinates(LatLng sw, LatLng ne)
        {
            this.sw = sw;
            this.ne = ne;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL)
        {
            //fetch places
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL)
            {
                //execute search
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try
                {
                    //try to fetch the data
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    //System.err.println(placeSearchStatus);
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200)
                    {
                        //we have an OK response
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("The website is never executed");
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }

        //Take the results from the URL, separate it, and get the Southwest and Northeast bound coordinates
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            LatLng SWBounds = null;
            LatLng NEBounds = null;
            try
            {
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                try
                {
                    JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONObject southWestLoc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("bounds").getJSONObject("southwest");
                    JSONObject northEastLoc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("bounds").getJSONObject("northeast");
                    SWBounds = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(southWestLoc.getString("lat")), Double.valueOf(southWestLoc.getString("lng")));
                    NEBounds = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(northEastLoc.getString("lat")), Double.valueOf(northEastLoc.getString("lng")));
                    setSouthWestBounds(SWBounds);
                    setNorthEastBounds(NEBounds);
                }
                catch (JSONException jse)
                {
                    System.err.println("The bounds were not computed");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("The JSON object was never read");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        //Blank the URL after the Map is displayed
        zipCodeURL = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //For safe measures, set to blank when activity reappears
        zipCodeURL = "";
    }

}
```

This is the logcat when I get to this class and press the button the calls the PlacePlace.IntentBuilder

```
04-16 21:19:24.513    7650-7650/com.example.apthagreat.faf D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
04-16 21:19:24.683    7650-7671/com.example.apthagreat.faf D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9d2dd000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb4ad4d60
04-16 21:19:24.703    7650-7650/com.example.apthagreat.faf I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24ce418b time:4496690
04-16 21:19:24.973    7650-7650/com.example.apthagreat.faf V/ActivityThread﹕ updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{26aa4d14 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1b7217fa {com.example.apthagreat.faf/com.example.apthagreat.faf.ActivityListScreen}} show : false
04-16 21:19:26.633    7650-7650/com.example.apthagreat.faf D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-16 21:19:26.813    7650-7671/com.example.apthagreat.faf D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9d2e9600 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9f64add0
04-16 21:19:27.543    7650-7650/com.example.apthagreat.faf W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-16 21:19:28.143    7650-7650/com.example.apthagreat.faf I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24ce418b time:4500135
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: I did try debugging and the logcat says the same information

Comment: Atleast can you tell while execution of which method app closes?

Comment: No i can't. I've put system print lines throughout the class and none of the error print lines i put in occur

Comment: You can put a break point in the first line of onCreate method of main activity. You will get to know what is happening.

Comment: If you are not connected to internet then also it'll closes immediately. So check your internet connection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Make sure you enable **"Places API for Android"** and not just **"Places API"** in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com). **"Places API for Android"** will not show up under "APIs & Auth/APIs" because it isnt a popular API (yet). You will have to search for it using the API search box.

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'

@MayankGarg  try the above line it will Compile correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` to `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) is a link to more information.

Answer (score 1):

Go through those:

1. Check **[Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)** to check is the "**Place SDK for Android**" is enabled
2. Add credentials for the enabled API. Use your package name and SHA1 key.
3. Check AndroidManifest file for, is added API key and meta tags and permissions

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/key_google_map"/>
```

Make sure have have you define in manifest file.