# The map disappears after 3 seconds from launching the activity when I use Place Picker to pick a point on the map

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to let the user get the place from the map , so i used place picker using Geocoder , but the map disappears after 3 seconds

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drive111);

    btnPicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectPlace00);

    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder  builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Intent intent = builder.build(driveFragment111.this);

    //(Activity) getContext());
    startActivityForResult( (intent) ,PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            AddressData addressData = data.getParcelableExtra(data.getDataString());
            btnPicker.setText((int) addressData.getLatitude());

        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PlacePicker.IntentBuilder closes immediately after opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688642/placepicker-intentbuilder-closes-immediately-after-opening)

Comment: @MuhammadAwais .  so do I have to pay if I want to use google places api ?